# Does a map with these properties have a name?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

A derivation $D$ is a map on an algebra $A$ over a field $F$, $D:A \rightarrow A$ such that $D$ is an $F$-linear map and the following holds:

$$D(ab)=aD(b)+D(a)b$$ $$\forall ab\in A$$

Is there a name for the similar construct where $D$ is a map with $A$ an algebra with the field $F$, $D:A \rightarrow F$ such that again:

$$D(a+b) = D(a) + D(b)$$
$$D(ab) = D(b)a + D(a)b$$
$$\forall a,b\in A$$

Comment: $a\in R_1, D(b)\in R_2$ how you define $aD(b)$ ?

Comment: @TsemoAristide I just realized that I asked wrong......thank you for pointing out my incosistency

Answer (score 2):

Such a map goes by the name of [*derivation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivation_(differential_algebra)).

Comment: No.....a derivation goes from the algebra to itself

Comment: @DarthRubik And if, as you seem to assume, the field is canonically embedded into the algebra, what's the difference?

Comment: @Darth A derivation can also take values in a module.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I see.....

Comment: @DarthRubik Reading more carefully, your second question is still inconsistent: $D(ab)=aD(b)+D(a)b$ still does not make sense if the image of $D$ is in $F$ and $F$ does not contain $A$.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli I see your point.....

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Or maybe the correct answer is "such map goes by the name zero".